# How to display tree of data at shell?

Tags: shell, treeview

Unix is known for simple programs that do one thing and can be used in a pipeline. Is there any Linux programs that takes in data which has a tree structure and displays it at the shell as an ASCII tree view? It could even be something as simple as using tab for indenting children nodes in display.

Examples of such display are those by pstree (for processes) or tree (for directories).

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know any program that will do this for you, but you can still use sed.

For example this works for directories :

```
ls -R $path | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

From this you can't create a script `tree.sh` that will take the path to display as an argument and set that script as an alias.

**tree.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
       ls -R $1 | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
      shift
done
```

You can probably do the same from the output of a `pstree`.